# Dynamic page navigation depending on logic at start up

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

How do you dynamically set a page to navigate to depending on some certain logic at the app start up with the Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 api

Comment: As you are targeting Silverlight, the information in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx) should be still actual.

Answer (score 0):

This question [Navigate directly into the app without logging in again Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201141/) also talks about the same requirement.

Give a logic behind on how you're going to navigate to the initial page of the app right after the splash.